# JPA Named query

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Hey I'm new to JPA and fairly new to SQL and I need to write a slection query

I need to :

"Select all payments where the amount is more than the average value of all USD payments"

I have a JPA entity :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private Long id;
private String account;
private double amount;
private String currency;
```

I tried with :

```
@NamedQuery(name="payByUSD" , query="SELECT x FROM Payment x WHERE x.amount > (SELECT AVG(x.amount)from Payment)")
```

but I got the following error:

```
- The FROM clause must defined at least one identification variable declaration.
- The right expression is missing from the arithmetic expression.
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: `AVG(amount)` instead of `AVG(Payment)`.

Comment: Ok, I changed it to x.amount but I stlle have these errors :  - The FROM clause must defined at least one identification variable declaration.
 - The right expression is missing from the arithmetic expression.

Comment: That is from the inner SELECT; do as with x. Instead of SQL we are doing objects in JPA queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT x FROM Payment x 
WHERE x.amount > (SELECT AVG(p.amount) from Payment p)
```

Your subquery is

```
SELECT AVG(x.amount) from Payment
```

, and `x` is not defined.